# Add new column based on coincidence of two columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have these two starter data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame("Location" = c('NE', 'SW', 'NW'), "Time" = c('0400', '1620', '2110'), "Assignment" = c('Painter', 'Astronaut', 'Bartender'), "Frequency" = c(84, 122, 139))
df1
    Location  Time  Assignment  Frequency
 1  NE        0400  Painter     84
 2  SW        1620  Astronaut   122
 3  NW        2110  Bartender   139

df2 <- data.frame("Location" = c('NE', 'SW', 'NW', 'NW', 'SE'), "Time" = c('0400', '1620', '2110', '2240', '1410'), "Assignment" = c('Scripter', 'Port Patrol', 'Lawyer', 'Supplier', 'Youtuber'), "Frequency" = c(82, 126, 144, 94, 102))
df2
    Location  Time  Assignment  Frequency
 1  NE        0400  Scripter    84
 2  SW        1620  Port Patrol 122
 3  NW        2110  Lawyer      139
 4  NW        2240  Supplier    94
 5  SE        1410  Youtuber    102
```

Suppose I didn't know which data frame was larger. But in this case, df2>df1 , so now I want to try and see which values of the columns 'Location' AND 'Time' coincide. For these equivalents, add a new column stating 'Coincide'. If not, this column should be NA.

For this, I tried:

```
df3$NewCol <- NA
df3$NewCol[df1$Location == df2$Location & df1$Time == df2$Time] <- 'Coincide'
```

or

```
if(df1$Location == df3$Location & df1$Time == df3$Time) {
df3$NewCol <- 'Coincide'
 }
```

(In this ones I created a new df3 which is a merge of df1 + df2)

But on both of these tries I get the error:

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Which I believe is a problem on both data frames having different lengths, but how could I overcome this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the first question of adding a new column with `'Coincide'`.

We can do a full join with `df1` and `df2` which would give all the entries present in both the dataframes irrespective of their size. We can then check for `NA` values and assign `'Coincide'` or `NA` value based on that.

```
all_data <- merge(df1, df2, by = c('Location', 'Time'), all = TRUE)
all_data$new_col <- c('Coincide', NA)[(rowSums(is.na(all_data[-c(1:2)])) > 0) + 1]

all_data
#  Location Time Assignment.x Frequency.x Assignment.y Frequency.y  new_col
#1       NE 0400      Painter          84     Scripter          82 Coincide
#2       NW 2110    Bartender         139       Lawyer         144 Coincide
#3       NW 2240         <NA>          NA     Supplier          94     <NA>
#4       SE 1410         <NA>          NA     Youtuber         102     <NA>
#5       SW 1620    Astronaut         122  Port Patrol         126 Coincide
```

You can then select only the columns that you need for further analysis.